# mediaelement: multi video/audio with setSrc

Tags: mediaelement.js

It would be nice, when I can set more urls with setSrc.

With Tag I can do that:

```
<audio>
  <source ...>
  <source ...>
</audio>
```

How can I do that with setSrc?

Answer (score 0):

i have found it out:

```
MediaElement.setSrc([
  {src:'audiofile.mp3', type:'audio/mp3'},
  {src:'audiofile.ogg', type:'audio/ogg'}
]);
```